# MongoDB and PartialFilterExpression capabilities

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.2 is now providing a filter expression to partially index the collection.
Based on that feature, I wonder how MongoDB could help me for the following case.

I do have many pre defined queries very near the filter expression. The principle will be to create many filter expression index.

The index will in fact keep the ids of the maching document and will be updated on each document changes.

For performance reason, I prefer to use the index engine from MongoDB that trying to use an external tools with Trigger solution.

How could I accomplish such feature by extending MongoDB. Any others noSQL could help ?

Thanks

Comment: could you be more specific? imho you just answered you question.

Comment: Let's say that I have function index ( like in Oracle ) like:
 Function Index 1: country: "FR", "Age" > 10
 Function Query 2: country: "EN", "Age" between 10 and 20
As MongoDB supports already partial index with a filterCondition,
how MongoDB could manage function index like in Oracle  to boost the performance ?

Comment: i am not familiar with oracle - but we can discuss your problem here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues

Comment: What i'm looking for is a pre computed index comparable to materialized view. I guess, by extending the partial index with its filter expression, I could have in future Mongo version a solution to have real time processing based on some filter expression.

Comment: The kind of index is  a Bitmap Index based on a filter expression. Does MongoDB support such index ?